# How to reduce this with all 4 of normal applicative by-name by-value?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Given

```
mult = \x -> \y -> x*y
```

I am trying to reduce

```
(mult (1+2)) (2+3)
```

with each of the strategies:

- normal-order
- applicative-order
- call-by-name
- call-by-value

My attempt:

For both *applicative and by-value* I get the same (because no intermediate lambda expression contains anything reducible, hence applicative does not do reduction under lambda either)

```
(mult (1+2)) (2+3)
(mult 3) (2+3)
(\y -> 3*y) (2+3)
(\y -> 3*y) 5
3*5
15
```

With *normal and by-name*: I am supposed to substitute `(2+3)` into the body of `(mult (1+2))`. But that does not have a body, unless I do a reduction. But then it is not normal-order, nor call-by-name, since it is not the outermost I reduce. Hence it seems to me that these evaluation strategies "get stuck". But I am probably misunderstanding smth.

Please show me the correct evaluation.